# Passport number or DOB needed when flying from China to US?

Tags: tickets, international-travel, china, china-airlines

I booked a ticket from China to US for my girlfriend online from a 3rd party company (Cheap Tickets). On the e-ticket, the main information contained is her full name and booking and confirmation number. Date of birth and passport number are not on it. It is also in English.

Are there any problems with this? Are DOB and passport number needed to receive the boarding pass? Is it okay that it is in English?

She is flying out of Beijing (PEK) with Etihad Airways.

Comment: Passport and DOB will be needed before she flies - but not on the ticket. BTW, if she is Chineses, I am assuming that her visa is in order.

Comment: @AleksG She has a passport and visa, which contains her DOB. However, I'm pretty sure it is not in Etihad Airways' system. Not sure if that is a problem or not.

Comment: It'll get into the airline's system when she goes to check in for the flight.

Comment: @AleksG Okay, thanks for the help. Maybe I'm just paranoid, haha.

Comment: The actual electronic (or paper) "ticket" doesn't even have a space for the passport number or date of birth, only the passenger's name. (They might be recorded separately in the reservation system.) The API is only needed at check in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You'll be fine**.  While all Etihad flights to the US [require APIS information](http://www.etihad.com/en-us/before-you-fly/us-preclearance/service-requirements/), it can be [provided on check-in](http://cms.prod.etihadairways.com/sites/etihad/trades/global/en/PoliciesandProcedure/Pages/apis.aspx) at Beijing.

Alternatively, to speed up things a bit, she can likely log into Etihad's site to manage her flight and enter the information there.